# How to fix page scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i'm try to control page jump when i'm click on the tab id, my demo link 
http://jsfiddle.net/bala2024/x9ypj/

```
function showSection( sectionID ) {
    $('div.section').css( 'display', 'none' );
    $('div'+sectionID).css( 'display', 'block' );
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    if (
        $('ul#verticalNav li a').length &&
        $('div.section').length
    ) {
        $('div.section').css( 'display', 'none' );
        $('ul#verticalNav li a').each(function() {
            $(this).click(function() {
                showSection( $(this).attr('href') );
            });
        });
        $('ul#verticalNav li:first-child a').click();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

prevent the default behavior of the anchor tags. check out the updated fiddle

```
$('#verticalNav a').click(function(){
    return false;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/x9ypj/1/

Comment: Hi Abhideve, url with #section2 not working, how i fix that one.

Answer (score 1):

First off, you can replace

```
.css( 'display', 'block' );
```

with just

```
.show();
```

And,

```
.css( 'display', 'none' );
```

with

```
.hide();
```

Finally, in order to prevent link behavior, you need to change this block.-

```
$('ul#verticalNav li a').each(function() {
    $(this).click(function() {
        showSection( $(this).attr('href') );
    });
});
```

for this.-

```
$('ul#verticalNav li a')
    .click(function(e) {
        showSection( $(this).attr('href') );
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to use this:

```
$('#verticalNav a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```